# How host dynamic site using filezilla

Tags: mysql, xampp, filezilla

Please somebody help! I have just developed a dynamic website using XAMPP as my localhost server. And I am only good in hosting non-dynamic sites. Now I want to use Filezilla to host the files which are now on the XAMPP localhost server, with MySQL tables populated with some data. 
I know that the html, the css, the js & the php files I developed, and the folders containing the pictures, videos and other files will be included in the upload using Filezilla client.
But the difficulty here is which folders and files in the XAMPP will be included to carry along my database (tables and the data inside).
Please somebody good in this should help me out, if my question does not sound vague! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the server you are using.  "Filezilla" is not a server for hosting files, it is an FTP program to move your files to the server.

Typically there is a folder called "www" or "public_html" on linux servers where your Document_Root should go (index.php, index.html, etc.).  This is usually located in "/var/www/html" or "~/public_html" but it can vary from server to server.  You should upload your main website files into that directory keeping the folder structure you have locally.

To transfer the database, you'll first need to get an SQL dump of the database on your local XAMPP server.  XAMPP should come with PHPMyAdmin to do this easily: http://www.instructables.com/id/Backing-up-your-SQL-database-using-XAMPP-and-phpMy/

Then, you'll need a tool to connect to the database server on your new host to create the database, users, password, and input the SQL dump and point your configuration file to use that database (typically the host is "localhost").  This can be done via SSH, a tool such as MySQL Workbench, or PHPMyAdmin if it is installed on your server.

Your question is pretty broad because we don't have server information, but this should be a good starting point

Comment: If this answer helped solve your problem, please accept it :)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Bryan for this great contribution. I understood your first and second paragraph, but not clear on the last two paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Bryan for this great contribution. I understood your first and second paragraph, but not clear on the last two paragraphs. What I'm trying to say here is I have already developed the site and the database with the help of PHPMyAdmin in the XAMPP. I know how to transfer the files to my site from the localhost, but the question here is which files and folders am I including in the transfer if I want to carry along my database to the online server, since this is a dynamic website. I am using Filezilla for the Transfer.

Comment: In your PHPMyAdmin there is an "Export" tool that lets you get a .SQL file of your database.  You cannot upload your database through Filezilla, you need to use database management tool that is on the online server (most hosts give you access to PHPMyAdmin to do this). If you have PHPMyAdmin installed on your online server, you can use the "Import" function to upload your .SQL file.  You should check with your host on what tools they provide to upload the database files